# c# solve equations to unknown parameter

Tags: c#, equation

I have *one physical-formular* set in my application and want to calculate a parameter.

Theorie:

```
548.1 = 27 * π / x + 73 - 2622.0 (demonstration example)
```

now I want to become the x value with a solve like so;

Solve(expr,vars) -> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html

The Wolfram API needs an internet connection, so nothing for me.

Is there any simple functionality to adjust the formula to get out the parameter to one side like;
https://quickmath.com/#c=solve_algstepsequationsolve&v239=25%253D%25281%2F5%2529%255E%25282-x%2529&v240=x

and calculated it afterwards?

Comment: You can make great money if you solve that.

Comment: is this... a programming question? also, some formulae are irreducible; but in the general case: build a dual AST (left and right) and shuffle it, performing the same operations on both sides; not trivial, and not always possible; but not impossible to hack at for most simple cases, either

Comment: Could mXParser help?   http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/solving-equation-fx-0/

Comment: alternatively; use numerical estimation methods to solve the method by iteratively improving the value; many such methods exist

Comment: I tried mxparser already, but the solve function isnt what i want. The syntax there is: `solve(exp,a,b)` I need to set the a and b values and everytime i change these values, the results changes too. So nothing for me :(

Comment: I think I'd [math-parse](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/88435/simple-guide-to-mathematical-expression-parsing) left and right side of the equation and try to isolate the node with `x` value

Comment: @Rafalon Do you know any adjustment functionality to isolate the unknown parameter "x"?

Comment: You'd have to revert the furthest nodes to the other side of the equation (if it's a + then you convert to a - for example). Of course you have to set the rules right, and not forget edge cases (when you have `something / x` add `1 / ...` - for example)

Comment: But do you need to solve arbitrary equations? If you have a limited set of equations, just solve them outside of your application and then implement the solution.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have over 20 physical-formulars and dont want to solve every formular to their parameters. At the end i have over 200 formulars... so this solve fucntionality would be veerrrrrry nice. But everytime i know all parameters except one

Comment: How are the equations coming into your application? As strings? Or as are they code?

Comment: there are now coded like: `double result =  p1 / p2 * p3...` the p1,p2,p3.. are handover parameters

Answer (score 0):

C# is a programming language. Root finding is a specific operation. There is not a built-in method for finding roots in a given equation in C#. You should either implement yourself or use third party libraries.

Comment: Can you recommend a library? Do little F# functions help? The problem is, that the calcuting process should go very fast.

Comment: No, there is no library I can recommend.

Comment: There are plenty of stuff to choose from, see e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6721736/132250